# Apex class disabled in my new Org

Tags: apex, developer-org

Hello I just signed up for a new developer org and i found that the apex classes are disabled on that. How to enable them ?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

> Check if your current user's profile have permission for Apex classes
>   or not.

[image]